# No video output by WebChimera and wcjs-prebuilt on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: electron, vlc, libvlc

WebChimera is not supported Linux officially, But I have used that on a Ubuntu 16.04 by upgrading VLC to 2.2.4 and using a pre-built package fount at [WebChimera.js v0.2.7 Releases](https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera.js/releases) (WebChimera.js_electron_1.4.13_x64_linux.zip)

I have built [WebChimera](https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera.js) myself on Ubuntu 16.04 and VLC 2.2.2 (official version of VLC on 16.04). Every thing is OK for some videos but for some of videos, I just can hear the audio when playing and there is a black screen (no video output but audio is OK). I don't want to upgrade my VLC to 2.2.4. How can I fix this problem?

On electron v1.6.8, console writes this error:

```
[h264 @ 0x2e3c62ba0880] No start code is found.
[h264 @ 0x2e3c62ba0880] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
```

on older electron versions like v1.4.0 or v1.1.0, this error is written:

```
[h264 @ 0x1262f42c8480] no frame!
```

or

```
[h264 @ 0x3f08b31d5000] The maximum value for lowres supported by the decoder is 0
```

sample output of vlc is:

```
majid@majid-K55VD:~$ vlc --version  
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
VLC version 2.2.2 Weatherwax (2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
Compiled by buildd on lgw01-18.buildd (Mar 28 2017 11:23:57)
Compiler: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public     License;
see the file named COPYING for details.
Written by the VideoLAN team; see the AUTHORS file.
```

sample output of ffmpeg is:

```
majid@majid-K55VD:~$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-    suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating VLC to 2.2.4 and upper resolved my problem.